# C# - Downloading data file through REST API

Tags: c#, rest

I am trying to write a program to download a data file exposed through a REST API. The owner of the data has not documented the API. I used Chrome's Developer tool to get the endpoint and  powershell command to call the API. I was able to run the Powershell command and get the data downloaded. However, when I try to save the command as a Powershell script and try to invoke it from a C# program, the downloaded file contains gibberish.

Heres my C# program:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();            
ps.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\DataDownload.ps1")).Invoke();
```

and heres the ps1 file. (all values redacted)

[image]

I am suspecting auth issues here. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Either you can catch the response of `Invoke-WebRequest` to a variable to see what are the response header. Also, you can wrap the request call with try/catch to catch the non success message from Web API call.

Comment: I do wonder why you're hacking together a mix of C# and PowerShell scripting rather than simply writing the appropriate C# code to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Remember: **always** post your code as text, **never** as a screenshot.